# Getting params out of an array - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm still learning here and i'm sure its something pretty easy i can't figure out. But basically,i'm working on an e-commerce platform. 
When a customer clicks checkout in the cart, the new action is triggered in the Orders controller.
However, i'm trying to load the **line_items** that are in the cart onto the checkout page.

So far, i've only been able to load one of them.
If there are 2 -3 items in the cart, i want the customer to be able to see what he is paying for.

In the controller, i have:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @item = current_cart.line_items 
end
```

In the view i have: 
**UPDATED**

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js">
  data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
  data-currency="gbp"
  <% @item.each do |t| %>
  data-name="<%=t.quantity %> &times; <%= t.product.title %>"
  data-description="<%= t.size %>, <%= t.color %>"
  data-amount="<%= (t.product.price * 100) %>" 
  <% end %>
  data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"
  data-shipping-address="true"
  data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

My issue is there's clearly 2 items in the cart when i look in the console. But i just can't get that to show as it seems **@item** is an array.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all please rename you instance variable to indicate that it is a collection. When you iterating the items your containing element seems to be the same. You are always populating the same data attributes. You should create/update new container each iteration.

Comment: @Anton Can you please write an example of what you mean if you don't mind?

Comment: I don't know what is your implementation.. try add enclose the data-attributes with some html tag.. lets say div: <div data-name="" data-description="" data-amount=""></div> . Then inspect the source to check if the elements were created as expected.

Comment: @anton updated the code with the full form.

Comment: I didn't use stripe but as far as I can understand and read here : <https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails> This script tag is used to submit the entire cart with totals. You can iterate the items and print them into the page and populate totals to the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, you want to show two items from `@item` instance variable; that means you are showing those values in show action but fetching in new action. I think you need to fetch it in show action and then apply an each loop.

```
def show
  @item = current_cart.line_items 
end
```

Then in 'show' view, loop it through each loop.

Comment: did it worked?, yes even though it is form it depends on where you render it, that action should make query.

Comment: No it didn't. I got an `undefined method  'each' for nil:NilClass` error

Comment: @AshishJambhulkar, He speaks about checkout page so the action is orders#new.. or something like that.